# Using XML-contained data fields for summarizing windows events in log analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

In Azure Log Analytics, I am trying to analyze events created by the Task Scheduler and group them by the executed task's name.

The basic query looks like

```
Event 
| where Source == "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler" 
and TimeGenerated > ago(24h) 
and EventLog == "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational" 
and EventID == 201
```

I am struggling with the task of grouping the results by the scheduled tasks' names as the names are contained in XML-encoded data in the `ParameterXML` and `EventData` attributes which have the following formats:

*ParamterXML:*

```
<Param>\MyScheduledTasksName</Param>
<Param>{1F1893C6-0696-430C-9738-50B068DDE37B}</Param>
<Param>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Param> 
<Param>0</Param>
<Param>9684</Param>
```

*EventData:*

```
<DataItem type="System.XmlData" time="2019-06-13T11:18:45.4806563+02:00" sourceHealthServiceId="D4165670-2EBA-67E0-FF6B-1D838007CE5B">
  <EventData Name="ActionSuccess" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <Data Name="TaskName">\MyScheduledTasksName</Data>
    <Data Name="TaskInstanceId">{1F1893C6-0696-430C-9738-50B068DDE37B}</Data>
    <Data Name="ActionName">C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="ResultCode">0</Data><Data Name="EnginePID">9684</Data> 
 </EventData>
</DataItem>
```

How would I go about parsing the XML task name so I could use it for grouping / summarizing in a pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an example for using `parse_xml()`, combined with `mv-apply` to access only specific elements in the XML payload, e.g. `TaskName` in this case:

```
datatable(id:int, EventData:string)
[
    1, '<DataItem type="System.XmlData" time="2019-06-13T11:18:45.4806563+02:00" sourceHealthServiceId="D4165670-2EBA-67E0-FF6B-1D838007CE5B">\n  <EventData Name="ActionSuccess" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">\n    <Data Name="TaskName">\\MyScheduledTasksName</Data>\n    <Data Name="TaskInstanceId">{1F1893C6-0696-430C-9738-50B068DDE37B}</Data>\n    <Data Name="ActionName">C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe</Data>\n    <Data Name="ResultCode">0</Data><Data Name="EnginePID">9684</Data>\n </EventData>\n</DataItem>',
    2, '<DataItem type="System.XmlData" time="2019-06-13T11:18:45.4806563+02:00" sourceHealthServiceId="D4165670-2EBA-67E0-FF6B-1D838007CE5B">\n  <EventData Name="ActionSuccess" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">\n    <Data Name="TaskName">\\MyOtherTask</Data>\n    <Data Name="TaskInstanceId">{1F1893C6-0696-430C-9738-50B068DDE37B}</Data>\n    <Data Name="ActionName">C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe</Data>\n    <Data Name="ResultCode">0</Data><Data Name="EnginePID">9684</Data>\n </EventData>\n</DataItem>'
]
| mv-apply EventData = parse_xml(EventData).DataItem.EventData.Data on 
(
    where EventData['@Name'] ==  'TaskName'
    | project TaskName = EventData['#text']
)
```

The query above returns the following table:

```
| id | TaskName              |
|----|-----------------------|
| 1  | \MyScheduledTasksName |
| 2  | \MyOtherTask          |
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. A subsequent `| summarize count() by tostring(TaskName)` gave me the result I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for the parse_xml() function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/parse-xmlfunction